# Creating custom fields for Joomla 3.x modules

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm creating a module for Joomla 3.x and I would like to have a custom parameters. I checked the [Creating a custom form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) page on joomla docs and I checked a 3rd party module which has custom fields, but I can't make it work.

Probably I'm missing a step or doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

this is what I did so far:

In the modules xml file I added the custom fieldset and field like this:

```
<fielset name="TITLE" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_mymodule/admin">
  <field type="customfield" name="custom" />
</fieldset>
```

than I created a file called customfield.php and in the file I have this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldCustomfield extends JFormField {
    protected $type = 'customfield';

    public function getInput(){
        $custom_form = '<div class="input-prepend input-append">';
        $custom_form .= '<div class="media-preview add-on"><span title="" class="hasTipPreview"><span class="icon-eye"></span></span></div>';
        $custom_form .= '<input type="text" id="jform_params_backgroundimage" class="input-small hasTipImgpath" readonly value="" aria-invalid="false" name="jform[params][backgroundimage]" />';
        $custom_form .= '<a rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}" href="index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;asset=com_modules&amp;author=&amp;fieldid=jform_params_backgroundimage&amp;folder=" title="'.JText::_('JSELECT').'" class="modal btn">'.JText::_('JSELECT').'</a>';
        $custom_form .= '<a onclick="jInsertFieldValue('', \'jform_params_backgroundimage\'); return false;" href="#" title="" class="btn hasTooltip" data-original-title="'.JText::_('JCLEAR').'"><span class="icon-remove"></span></a>';
        $custom_form .= '</div>';

        return $custom_form;
    }
}
?>
```

this is basicly a copy of the media field type, but this is only for testing, obviously I wouldn't need custom field for this.

The fieldset shows up in the admin as a tab as it should be, but the filed doesn't. Than I added the addfilepath to `<fields name="params" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_carousel/admin">` as I saw in a 3rd party module, but still nothing.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

only use this code,do not use class

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$custom_form = '<div class="input-prepend input-append">';
        $custom_form .= '<div class="media-preview add-on"><span title="" class="hasTipPreview"><span class="icon-eye"></span></span></div>';
        $custom_form .= '<input type="text" id="jform_params_backgroundimage" class="input-small hasTipImgpath" readonly value="" aria-invalid="false" name="jform[params][backgroundimage]" />';
        $custom_form .= '<a rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}" href="index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;asset=com_modules&amp;author=&amp;fieldid=jform_params_backgroundimage&amp;folder=" title="'.JText::_('JSELECT').'" class="modal btn">'.JText::_('JSELECT').'</a>';
        $custom_form .= '<a onclick="jInsertFieldValue('', \'jform_params_backgroundimage\'); return false;" href="#" title="" class="btn hasTooltip" data-original-title="'.JText::_('JCLEAR').'"><span class="icon-remove"></span></a>';
        $custom_form .= '</div>';

        echo $custom_form;
```